# How to check browser's support for brotli compression on client application side?

Tags: javascript, http-compression, brotli, http-accept-encoding

I am asking this question for educational purposes.
I have hosted my static assets on S3 with Cloud front. I want to apply brotli and gzip compression during the build process.

As per articles available on various platforms It is possible to add content-type and intercept S3 origin requests using Lambda@edge. But Lambda@edge is available with region US-east so it is not available to our region.

So is it possible to check the browser's compatible compression on the client-side when we are adding scripts for static assets?

Only solution I could find online is: [Can JavaScript detect if the user's browser supports gzip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153220/can-javascript-detect-if-the-users-browser-supports-gzip)

Answer (score 1):

Edge Lambdas are always in us-east-1.
For example: If your bucket is in paris, your cloudfront will always be global and your Lambda@edge too. In the Console it's located in us-east-1.